# handlebars button id to ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, handlebars.js

Imagine I have a handlebar template like this:

```
       {{#each this}}
           {{username}}
           <form method="post" id="form-id-{{tirID}}">
              <input type="button" id="btn-id-{{tirID}}">
           </form>
       {{/each}}
```

This one loops through data and works great with AJAX get method. However I would like to also use the button inside this template. I can give it a ID like I do above in the template. But how can I target the specific button to activate a AJAX post method ? The following wont work because I am not operating in the template anymore so {{ x }} can not be found:

```
       $('#btn-id-{{tirID}}').on('click', '.mydiv', function(event) {

           $.ajax({
                 type:'POST',
                 url: 'and so on....

       }
```

Hope someone have a suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
{{#each this}}
    {{username}}
    <form method="post" id="form-id-{{tirID}}">
       <input type="button" id="btn-id-{{tirID}}" class="js-btn" data-id="{{tirID}}">
    </form>
{{/each}}
```

Then listen to js-btn and use the data property to get the id.

```
$('.js-btn').on('click', '.mydiv', function(event) {
       var id = $(this).data().id;
       $.ajax({
             type:'POST',
             url: 'and so on....

   }
```